# xsd validation based on two keys

Tags: xml, xsd, xmllint

I want to validate the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <root1>
        <items>
            <item id="1">
                <interfaces>
                    <interface id="0"/>
                    <interface id="1"/>
                    <interface id="2"/>
                </interfaces>
            </item>
            <item id="2">
                <interfaces>
                    <interface id="10"/>
                    <interface id="11"/>
                    <interface id="2"/>
                </interfaces>
            </item>
        </items>
        <connections>
            <connection id="1">
                <point item="1" interface="0"/>
                <point item="2" interface="10"/>
            </connection>
            <connection id="2">
                <point item="1" interface="1"/>
                <point item="2" interface="11"/>
            </connection>
            <connection id="3">
                <point item="1" interface="2"/>
                <point item="2" interface="157"/>      <-- this one is not valid as there is no interface 157 under item 2.
            </connection>
        </connections>
    </root1>
</root>
```

That's the code for validating item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="root1" type="root1" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:keyref name="endPointIntfKeyRef" refer="interfaceKey">
            <xs:selector xpath="root1/connections/connection/point"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@interface"/>
        </xs:keyref>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="root1">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="items" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="item" type="item" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="connections" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="connection" type="connection" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="item">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="interfaces" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="interface" type="interface" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
                    <xs:unique name="interfaceKey">
                        <xs:selector xpath="interface"/>
                        <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
                    </xs:unique>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="interface">
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="connection">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="point" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="2">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="item" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="interface" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

But it produce 'More than one match found for key-sequence' that I do not want to have as interfaces are unique under specific item.

```
$ xmllint --noout --schema 1.xsd 1.xml 
1.xml:31: Schemas validity error : Element 'point': More than one match found for key-sequence ['2'] of keyref 'endPointIntfKeyRef'.
1.xml:32: Schemas validity error : Element 'point': No match found for key-sequence ['157'] of keyref 'endPointIntfKeyRef'.
1.xml fails to validate
```

How to get only second error 'Element 'point': No match found for key-sequence ['157'] of keyref 'endPointIntfKeyRef' and not the first one?

Comment: This key reference stuff was new to me. I found the following page to be a good explanation: http://zvon.org/xxl/XMLSchemaTutorial/Output/ser_keys_st5.html

Answer (score 1):

The error message is correct - there *are* two possible matches in the `interfaceKey` for the keyref value `2`.  To get the behaviour you require you would need a composite key value including the `item` ID as well as the `interface` ID that you could then `keyref` using both the `item` and `interface` attributes on `point`, but that would mean defining the `unique` constraint as

```
<xs:unique name="interfaceKey">
    <xs:selector xpath="interface"/>
    <xs:field xpath="../@id"/><!-- not allowed in 1.0 -->
    <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
</xs:unique>
```

and XML Schema 1.0 does not allow `..` in field or selector (restricted) XPath expressions.

Comment: Thanks, In what xml schema version it's supported?
And how to change my code to use it?

Comment: @vitalivanov XML Schema v1.1 allows the full XPath 2.0 language, but it's nowhere near as widely supported as 1.0. An alternative might be to investigate the use of schematron rules to express the constraints that you can't do in the basic schema.

Comment: So, this kind of validation is not possible in 1.0 schema?